# Simple Numeric Regex Match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi I'm having an issue doing a simple numeric match, what am I doing wrong:

Criteria:

```
1) Always anchor to start
2) Always Numeric 6-7 digits
3) Always Followed by _ (underscore)
```

Sample: (want to match everything before LoremIpsum)

```
1212384_LoremIpsum...
1266625_LoremIpsum...
234233_LoremIpsum...
2348199_LoremIpsum...
```

I have tried a couple of things: (Does not Match)

```
^[\d]{6-7}_
^[0-9]{6-7}_
```

If I do:

```
^[\d]{6}_
^[0-9]{7}_
```

I get matches, why can't I do variable length in this expression ?  What am I missing here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is with a comma:

```
{6,7}
```

Not:

```
{6-7}
```

Also, you don't have to put the `\d` in brackets:

```
^\d{6,7}_
```